# JAVA Send Post Request which contains XML String

Tags: java, xml, post, xmlhttprequest, http-post

### Problem Description

I'm trying to write a code which is sending POST request to the server. As server yet doesn't exist I can't test this part of code. With the request I must send XML as a String which look likes the string below:

```
String XMLSRequest = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Header><AuthenticationHeader><Username>Victor</Username><Password>Apoyan</Password></AuthenticationHeader></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>"
```

### Solution

```
String url = "https://testurl.com/somerequest";
URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

//add reuqest header
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

String urlParameters = String.format("request=%s", XMLSRequest);

// Send post request
con.setDoOutput(true);
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
wr.flush();
wr.close();
```

### Question

Is this right way to send String (XML like string) as POST request to the server?

Comment: First you need to serialize to JSON then send over HTTP.

Comment: Not sure why you are appending "request=" to the XML, other than that it looks ok.

Comment: @RomanC can you bring some example as a answer of how to send XML string via http connection in correct way?

Comment: @kharyam you mean `String urlParameters = XMLSRequest;` this is Okay ?

Comment: You should not use http connection.

Comment: @RomanC why not to use http?

Comment: I just need to send the request to server which contains XML as a string. This what I need to to Send as string

Comment: @ViToBrothers yes.  Or you can just delete that line and do wr.writeBytes(XMLRequest)

Comment: @ViToBrothers Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @RomanC I need to send POST request which contains XML as a string.

Comment: @RomanC I edit question you can check

Comment: Are you wanting to send XML in the body of the request (with Content-Type of text/xml)? Or are you wanting to send a parameter (Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded) whose value is xml and send it in the body of the request to avoid url length issues?

Comment: @BrettOkken I think for me better way is to send it in the body, as my string is very long (`XMLString`),so I can send it in a body of request also.

Comment: @ViToBrothers My question was what Content-Type are you wanting to use? What does the service you are calling expect?

Comment: @BrettOkken actually server does not exists, so I just need to simulate ending of XML String

Comment: @BrettOkken, so I need just to send XML String to not existing server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To POST a [SOAP request](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/ws_soap_httpbinding.asp), you would want to write the xml to the body of the request. You do not want to write it as a parameter of the request.

```
String url = "https://testurl.com/somerequest";
URL obj = new URL(url);
urlConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

// add request header
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8");

// Send post request
con.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream(); //get output Stream from con
os.write( XMLSRequest.getBytes("utf-8") );
os.close();
```

Comment: urlConnection not working my jax-rs web service which lib add for this work

Answer (score 1):

Specially this code works well for sending XML string in SOAP calling

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public static String sendXmlString(String xmlString){
    String xmlResponceString = "";
    try {
        // Replace here with your target URL
        URL url = new URL("http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Set timeout as per needs
        connection.setConnectTimeout(20000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(20000);

        // Set DoOutput to true if you want to use URLConnection for output.
        // Default is false
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        connection.setUseCaches(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        // Set Headers
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/xml");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5"); 
        // Write XML
        OutputStream outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
        byte[] b = xmlString.getBytes("UTF-8");
        outputStream.write(b);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

        // Read XML
        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        byte[] res = new byte[2048];
        int i = 0;
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        while ((i = inputStream.read(res)) != -1) {
            response.append(new String(res, 0, i));
        }
        inputStream.close();
        xmlResponceString = new String(response.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return xmlResponceString;
}
```